# Scala: "Static values" in traits?

Tags: scala, generic-programming, type-systems, type-theory, singleton-type

Let's say I have:

```
trait X {
  val x: String
}
```

Using mix-in, I can define a trait such as

```
trait XPrinter {
  self: X =>
  def printX: String = "X is: " + x
}
```

such that a value/object implementing `XPrinter` implements `x` and give its methods such as `printX` access to the values specified in `X` such as `x`.

So far, so good.

I want to know if there is a way of having a trait in the form of:

```
trait XDependent[T <: X] {
  def printX: String = ???
}
```

So that `XDependent` instances have access to the value of `T.x`, with `x` assumed to be a "static value" glued with the type definition.

Now I understand why `T.x` can't be accessed in `XDependent` since a type subtyping X doesn't even have to implement the value of `x` and T.x might be abstract.

I understand that while Scala offers path-dependent types so that an abstract type defined in X can be used in `XDependent`, as shown here:

```
trait X {
  type Y //which can be constrained as desired.
}

trait XDependent[T <: X]{
  def foo(v:T#Y)
  def bar: T#Y
}
```

it doesn't offer the same thing with values as there is a clear separation between types and values in Scala.

Now I have come across the ideas of **value-dependent types** and **literal-based types**. I want to know if the idea of "static value for types", as illustrated above, has much overlap with the these concepts and what the connections are.

I'd also like to know about the different approaches taken in different languages, to blur the separation between types and values, how compatible they are with Scala's type system, and what the complications are in terms of integrating "static values" with the type-system. ie, (Can they be)/ (what happens if they are) overriden by a subtype, etc.

Comment: Can you show a concrete problem or error that you're facing? This question seems quite general. Usually in most languages and especially in Scala there are many ways to structure some code to get certain properties. If we have a specific problem to solve, we can make recommendations towards that.

Comment: This is a question about Scala's type system and its approach to the connection between types and values. There is no "problem" to be solved.

Comment: After reading the comments to my attempted answer, I have to admit that I probably misunderstood the question, and still cannot quite figure out what your question is. If it's a question about a specific way to form types, then you might want to describe it in more detail, e.g. following the formation-introduction-elimination-computation-uniqueness specification style used in [HoTT A.2.4](http://www.heidelberg-laureate-forum.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Homotopy-Type-Theory_Univalent-Foundations-of-Mathematics.pdf). The last paragraph seems way too broad.

Comment: To clarify, I want to parameterise my generic type on another type, but I don't want this parameterisation to be through a value. I already know that as @Jasper-M suggests, values belong to objects and not types. This question aims to explore the potential bridges between types and values that languages such as Idris have made, how they differ with the Scala's type system, etc. and if it is possible to have somewhat simliar approaches in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

If you can relax the requirement that `XDependent` has to be a `trait`, and make it an `abstract class` instead, then it seems as if a typeclass which provides a single null-ary method `x` is exactly what you want:

Here is your base trait `X` (without `X.x` or anything, that wouldn't be "static"):

```
trait X
```

Now you can define a typeclass `HasStaticX[T]` that guarantees that for a type `T` we can give some string `x`:

```
trait HasStaticX[T] {
  def x: String
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
abstract class XDependent[T <: X : HasStaticX] {
  def printX: String = implicitly[HasStaticX[T]].x
}
```

What `HasStaticX` does is essentially building a compile-time partial function that can take type `T` and produce a string-value `x` associated with `T`. So, in a way, it's something like a function that takes types and returns values. If this is what you want, then nothing has to be done to for "integrating static values", it just works in the current non-experimental mainstream versions of Scala.

The "value-dependent types" would be exactly the other way round: those would be essentially "functions" that assign types to values.

Comment: Interesting. :) I tend to think of ad-hoc polymorphism as a mechnism to provide extention methods and not for tagging/identifying purposes, but yeah it can clearly work that way too. (btw, I don't think you really need `X` in your formulation)

Comment: Anyway, while your suggestion is syntactically comparable to what I have asked for, you're still using a value to access `x`. This value can be inherited, mixed in, passed as an explicit parameter or an implicit parameter but essentially all these approaches are the same. They are using values and not types.

Comment: @Mathsnoob Well, yes, in Scala everything is an object and you can only call methods on objects/values. Implicits are a way to summon a value for a certain type.

Comment: @Mathsnoob Then I don't understand what you are asking. All members are attached to some instance, be it an instance of a class, or a singleton object. Types are not objects, they are compile-time constructs. I cannot say whether I "need" `X` or not, because you have not stated what the actual problem is.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin In the original formulation, `X` was a base interface declaring `x`. In your formulation, this declaration is inside the type-class `HasStaticX` as such, `XDependent` isn't actually parameterised by `[T <: X : HasStaticX]` rather it's `[T : HasStaticX]`.

Comment: @Mathsnoob Obviously, `X` is not crucial for my code, I've just left it as-is, to demonstrate that the typeclass-constraint `: HasStaticX` does not conflict with the subtype constraint `T <: X`. Again: until you specify what exactly your problem is, *nothing* of the above is crucial at all.