# Use scala trait in scala object

Tags: scala, object, traits

So I got this Trait:

```
trait Ammo {
val maximum: Int
private var amount: Int = 0
val calibre: Calibre.Value
val metric: Metric.Value

def getAmount(): Int = return amount
def setAmount(i: Int): Unit = amount = i

def need(): Unit

override def toString(): String = return (amount + " " + metric.toString() + " of " + calibre.toString())

def difference(): Int = maximum - amount

def getMaximum(): Int = maximum

def reset() = amount = 0

def incAmount(i: Int) = amount += 1 }
```

I also created a Trait Rockets that extends Ammo

```
trait Rockets extends Ammo {
val calibre = Calibre.Rocket
val metric = Metric.Pods

def need(): Unit = Evaluator.getSupplyArray()(4) += difference()  }
```

Now I have an object in which I want to get access to the calibre of Rockets

```
object Evaluator {
def test() = print(Rockets.calibre) //???
```

but the way I try this does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: "Static values" in traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202845/scala-static-values-in-traits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rockets` is a trait (same would apply for class), not an instance (or Object).

You need to instantiate it:

```
val rocketsInstance = new Rocket {...}
print(rocketsInstance.calibre)
```

Comment: You can't instantiate a trait. What you are doing is to create an anonymous class that extends `Rocket` and instantiate that.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things you can create a *helper-object*, like:

`object Rockets extends Rockets`

Now you don't need to initialize it every time you want to use it. Just:

`println(Rockets.calibre)`